Concatenating video with ffmpeg/mkvmerge is out of order
I'm trying to concatenate these two single frame videos, but they always end up in the wrong order.
I've tried with ffmpeg:
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy outf.mkv

...where filelist.txt contains:
file '0012890a_9680.mkv'
file '0012890a_692070.mkv'

I've also tried with mkvmerge:
mkvmerge --output outm.mkv 0012890a_9680.mkv + 0012890a_692070.mkv --append-to 1:0:0:0

Both result in a 2 frame video with the frame order reversed.
Examining both resulting files with ffprobe -show_frames, it shows the frames in reverse (some lines omitted):
[FRAME]
key_frame=1
pts=42
pts_time=0.042000
best_effort_timestamp=42
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.042000
duration=41
duration_time=0.041000
pkt_pos=28240
pkt_size=88803

[FRAME]
key_frame=1
pts=0
pts_time=0.000000
best_effort_timestamp=0
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.000000
duration=41
duration_time=0.041000
pkt_pos=7976
pkt_size=20246

It's interesting to note that, according to pkt_pos, the frames are written in correct order, and the PTS is also correct, however the order listed is somehow incorrect.
If I reverse the order of the frames when sending to ffmpeg/mkvmerge, I get expected results. So it seems like the tools really want to put the second frame first.
I've also tried adding -bsf:v setts=ts=N to the ffmpeg command - the resulting PTS for the frames are 1 and 0, indicating correct packet order, but frames listed in reverse.
Does anyone know what's going on and how to solve the issue?
